# YouTube video posted comment show using C# Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I retrieve recently posted Comments/previous comments on any video in you tube in our application using C# ASP.Net.Please provide detail coding with dll

Thanks in Advance 
Ranjan.

Comment: Aw, please. You want us to do all of your work for you?

Comment: See http://www.youtube.com/dev

Comment: I wonder if certain parts of the world work that way

Answer (score 1):

[YouTube provides an API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html) that you could use to query different services and among other [retrieve comments for a given video](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Retrieve_comments).